# Connect to existing worker/task?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, subscribe

I wanted to get some opinions on how to go about a problem that I have.

Let's say I have a Server and a Client.

Client A connects and asks Server to spawn a new thread counting from 1 to 9999. Let's call this Thread A.

Client B connects and asks Server to spawn another thread counting down from 9999 to 1. Let's call this Thread B.

Thread A sends the calling client an update on the current count(i.e Thread A updates Client A, Thread B updates Client B).

Client A then disconnects and reconnects - The question i have is, how do i "resubscribe" to the current thread and continue getting updates?.

Are there any existing libraries to help with such tasks?

UPDATE: A bit more clarification if it helps:

These server threads will be running continuously in the background. e.g A client will connect to the server and start a task - This task will send messages back to the client. User knows that the task has been started as their client is receiving messages. User disconnects client but task is still processing in the background. User decides to check up on the task so they start the client up again and connect to the server. The last sentence is what I'm trying to achieve. My apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Why do you need to subscribe to the same thread? What if a number of clients connected to the server will spawn such a large number of threads that your server will become completely unresponsive?

Comment: I guess I was trying to use an example of what I'm trying to achieve - Basically resubscribing to a "Task" and continue getting updates.

Comment: Your architecture should be thread agnostic. i.e., each thread (fro example, from a thread pool) should be able to pick the work from the point where the previous thread left and continue the processing. However, your question contains too little details. For example, what kind of workload is assigned to the server threads? Is it something that's being processed only when the client connects, or is it continuous background process?

Comment: You should ask that in the *Programmer* section of StackExchange.

Comment: These server threads will be running continiously in the background. e.g A client will connect to the server and start a task - This task will send messages back to the client. User knows that the task has been started as their client is receiving messages. User disconnects client but task is still processing in the background. User decides to check up on the task so they start the client up again and connect to the server. The last sentence is what I'm trying to achieve. My apologies for not being clear.

Comment: @TotalApproved I would suggest you to add this description to the question. Also, without an example source code it is probably belongs to [Programmers@stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), as the question is more about the general way to do something than about concrete coding problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve you problem, try this:

Give the server a noticication when disconnecting 
"Authenticate" with a GUID which is created and sent to the server while first connect and on evere re-connect.

The server gets the GUID, holds them into a list and looks on every connect the server gets the GUID, looks for a existing entry and if there is a entry, you know the client was already connected. If not, then the client hasn't been connected, so the server has to create a new thread.

Instead of GUID you can use every other unique ID (such as MAC, checksum over the hardware, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an abstract example of what could be done. As the question doesn't specify concrete API's I will use made-up names and classes.

In order to identify the client we will use some unique identification token, let's call it `ClientToken`. The token will be allocated on the first client connection. It will be returned to the client for further authentication and it also will be used by the server for processing tasks' tracking.

The tracking part is some dictionary from token to the task data. The task data is a pair of task and its messages' queue:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ClientToken, TaskData> m_tasks;

class TaskData
{
    public Task ProcessingTask { get; set; }
    public BlockingCollection<Message> TaskMessages { get; } =
        new BlockingCollection<Message>();
}
```

Let's say ClientA connects by whatsoever means to the server. The part which takes care of the connection will look like:

```
//this is a kind of event handler, we should'n 'await' on it
async void OnClientConnectedAsync(Client client)
{
    var token = client.GetToken();
    TaskData taskData;
    if (token != null && m_tasks.TryGetValue(token, out taskData))
    {
        await ProcessMessagesAsync(taskData);
    }
    else
    {
        taskData = new TaskData();
        token = GenerateUniqueTokenBasedOnTheClientParameters(client);
        await client.SetTokenAsync(token);

        if (m_tasks.TryAdd(token, taskData))
        {
            taskData.ProcessingTask = 
                InitProcessingTask(
                    taskData.Messages, //will be used by the 
                    client);

            await ProcessMessagesAsync(taskData);
        }
    }
}

async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(TaskData taskData)
{
    while (client.IsConnected)
    {
        var message = taskData.Messages.Take();
        await client.SendAsync(message);
    }
}
```

You should decide on the `Messages` capacity and its items lifetime.